# How did Newton know gravity force between 2 objects although he could not examine it?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, history, estimation

Yes, Isaac Newton calculated it, I know.

But he could not examine the force between 2 objects (for example apple and human hand). And we all know there is gravity force between every 2 objects even though very small. Doesn't it all look like fitting numbers in equation until it looks good enough to work?

Are we sure that there is gravity between me and my laptop, and that it is as small as Newton said? Can we examine it now with 2019 technology?

Comment: [Related Video](https://youtu.be/OTMELHUAzSM)

Comment: You seem to have two questions here. One is how did Newton determine his law of gravitation. The second is can we say it's valid for smaller, everyday objects. I suggest asking the second question and editing accordingly to only focus on this question. The first one belongs on History of Math and Science SE

Comment: No you did very good job answering my question. very precise thank you. I am just now at the point where i think science doesn't want to admit it doesn't know something so it gives us wrong information. I am pretty sure Newton's law can be written in different form that will also fit the results. That's why I think that we know nothing, we just fit things we see in formulas till it looks good enough. Than we go for example in quantum world and it worth nothing

Comment: It is not necessary to test _every_ phenomenon predicted by a theory (e.g., the gravitational attraction between an apple and a human hand) in order for the theory to be accepted by the scientific community. It is enough if (a) the theory passes all of the tests that anybody actually _does_ perform, and (b) the theory _explains_ something (e.g., the motion of the planets) in a more satisfying way than any previous explanation.

Comment: @haris science admits what it doesn't know all the time. We sometimes give what we don't know funny names so we can be sure we're all talking about the same thing but that doesn't mean we fully understand it.As we learning things and throw off old ideas we publish new books. For example Newtons laws got tweaked by Einsteins. Before that Mercury had an embarrassing habit of showing up where it wasn't supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, we are sure. It has been possible for two centuries to measure the gravitational attraction of small masses in the laboratory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment This is how we know the value of $G$! BTW, I find your opinion of scientists to be highly insulting.

Comment: When I was a student we used a table top device to determine G directly from the attraction between two lead spheres.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Newton was able to explain, using his law of gravity, the astronomical observations (the movement of planets around the sun) of Kepler. It was not based on observing the gravitational force between common objects on the earth.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes he fits the results in formula. No scientific examination, only formula that covers all cases

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that Galileo gave the world a perfectly good law to describe how an apple falls from a tree, and Kepler gave the world a perfectly good law to describe how planets move in the heavens. What made Newton so famous (well, _one_ thing, anyway) was that he created a _single_ law that explained _both_ things. And, in so doing, he gave us the first real evidence that the laws that govern events in "the heavens" might be the same as the laws that govern events here on Earth.

Comment: @Haris It should be noted that this is how science works. Newton fit his model to the data he had available. He was unaware of the "quantum world". You can't test a model against data and understanding you don't have. Once something is uncovered to fail the model then you dig deeper. Hence we got GR. Just because a model of the universe fails in some instances doesn't mean the scientist was wrong, being dishonest, or that the model is useless

Answer (score 2):

Of course we are sure and of course we have checked. G can be determined directly from the attraction between two objects by the famous 18th century Cavendish experiment, which should be part of any physics curriculum. https://www.britannica.com/science/Cavendish-experiment